# Selenium Python can't find elements in a inner part of a web page with a separated scroll bar

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, webdriverwait

I'm trying to extract the names of 1268 companies from the website of industrial fair which has uploaded the exhibitors list on [this page](https://www.ecomondo.com/elenco-espositori/espositori-ecomondo).

Unfortunately selenium seems not to find the elements into the specific inner part of the webpage that contains companies' names and that has its own scrollbar.

[image: Page rendering]

Here's my code:

```
g = webdriver.Chrome()
g.get("https://www.ecomondo.com/elenco-espositori/espositori-ecomondo")
g.maximize_window()
time.sleep(2)
cookie = WebDriverWait(g,15).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="c-p-bn"]'))
)
cookie.click()
time.sleep(5)
element = g.find_element_by_class_name('sc-1aq2rfp-0 sc-li856a-3 eqfJYB euBeDv')
ActionChains(g).move_to_element_with_offset(element, 0, 0).perform()

company_name = g.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/a/div/div/span[1]')
print(company_name)
```

I also tried finding the element by xpath but the result is the same:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".sc-1aq2rfp-0 sc-li856a-3 eqfJYB euBeDv"}
```

After find the element I should scroll the sidebar down to make all the 1268 companies' name visible and eventually extract them but these are other stories.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

The desired elements are within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the desired *elements to be visible*.
- You can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.ecomondo.com/elenco-espositori/espositori-ecomondo')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='ACCETTA TUTTI I COOKIE E CONTINUA']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[starts-with(@src, 'https://ecomondo.app.swapcard.com/widget/event/ecomondo-and-key-energy-2020/exhibitors')]")))
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='infinite-scroll-component ']//a//following::span[1]")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['2LNG', 'D5/080', '3M ITALIA SRL', 'D3/011', '3META SRL', 'C6/002', '3U VISION SRL', 'A3/178', '3V GREEN EAGLE SPA', 'C1/105', '4 ESSE SRL', 'B4/007', '4SERVICE EUROPE S.R.L.', 'A3/027', '9-TECH SRL', 'SUD/064', 'A.B.C. BILANCE SRL', 'A2/068', 'A.C.R. DI REGGIANI ALBERTINO SPA', 'C1/152', 'A.E.C. SRL', 'A7/014', 'A.I.D.P.I. ASSOCIAZIONE IMPRESE DISINFESTAZIONEPROFESSIONALI ITALIANE', 'A5-C5/002 F', 'A.I.R.E.C. - ASSOCIAZIONE ITALIANA DEL RECUPERO ENERGETICO DA COMBUSTIBILI SOLIDI SECONDARI', 'B1/013', 'A.M.S. SPA - ATTREZZATURE MECCANICHE SPECIALI', 'C7/003', 'A.T. RICAMBI SRL', 'B1/164', 'A.U. ESSE SRL', 'A5/036', 'A2A ENERGIA SPA', 'B5/040', 'A2A ENERGY SOLUTIONS SRL', 'B5/040', 'A2A SPA', 'B5/040', 'AB ENERGY SPA', 'B5-D5/005', "ABICERT L' ENTE DI CERTIFICAZIONE", 'C4/009', "ACCIAI DI QUALITA' SPA", 'A1/058', 'ACEA SPA', 'D1/160', 'ACQUEDOTTO PUGLIESE SPA', 'D2/002', 'ACR+', 'B5/008', 'ACTA SRL', 'C1/002', 'ADAMBÍ - ADGENERA SRL', 'A5/143', 'ADAMOLI SRLS', 'C5/140', 'ADDAX MOTORS NV', 'A6/022', 'ADEME AGENCE DE LA TRANSITION ECOLOGIQUE', 'ADICOMP S.R.L.', 'D5/133', 'ADRIAECO', 'ADRIATICA ACQUE SRL', 'B4/029', 'AEBI SCHMIDT ITALIA SRL', 'A7/002', 'AEBIG - ASOCIACION ESPANOLA DE BIOGAS', 'ÆVOLUTION MATEUSZ WIELOPOLSKI CONSULTING', 'B5/045', 'AFFILOR SRL', 'A1/001', 'AGECO DUE SPA', 'C1/186', 'AGENCE NATIONALE DES DECHETS', 'B5/008', 'AGENDA SRL - EDIZIONI ACQUAGENDA, GASAGENDA, WATERGAS.IT', 'D3/192', "AGENZIA REGIONALE PER LA TUTELA DELL'AMBIENTE", 'D4/032', 'AGER PUGLIA', 'D2/002', 'AGRICOLUS SRL', 'SUD/063', 'AGRICOM SRL', 'D5/157', 'AGRIGARDEN AMBIENTE SRL A SOCIO UNICO', 'C1/056', 'AGRIPLAST SRL', 'C1/139', 'AGRITECH SRL', 'D4/011', 'AGROTEL GMBH', 'D5/029', 'AIMAG SPA', 'B3/109', 'AIR CLEAN SRL', 'A3/101']
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Comment: This answer is very easy-to-understand and professional, thank You.
BUT...even if now i am able to get companies' names my next task is to scroll down the <iframe> visual to load all the 1268 companies and get all the names.
How can I?

Comment: UPDATE: Today also the code you provided return a TimeoutException generated by
WebDriverWait(g, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='infinite-scroll-component ']//a//following::span[1]")))

Comment: And this happens when I try to manually scroll the iframe element pausing the programme with an input() command.